# Python read delay?

Tags: python, serial-port

I have written this bit of python code, this code connects to a serial device everything is working fine with the application BUT... when I am communicating with the device it prints the message late. so my user input is one step behind what the device actually wants to do. I know this is my mistake but I just cant see the silly thing I am doing, Can anyone please tell me why my messages might be coming through 1 action to late?

```
import serial
import sys
import time
ser = serial.Serial(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
prin = ""
def enterdata():
    global prin
    if (prin != "\r\n"):
        print("{{"+prin+"}}")
    prin=""
    ser = serial.Serial(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    scom = raw_input("type away:" )
    incli = str(scom)
    if (incli  == "exit the app"):
        print ("Exiting the data send, nothing was sent from the exit command")
    else:
        ser.write(incli+"\r\n")
        while True:
            data = ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
            data+= ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
            prin+=data
            # for i in range(len(data)):
            if (len(data) < 1 and prin != ""):
                break
        enterdata()


print ("Welcome to the serial CLI")
enterdata()
```

Comment: please correct indentation